# Why are items with unique permissions being affected when I delete Users/Groups in the list permission

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2010, csom

I'm new to SharePoint and csom. I'm trying to figure out how to change existing group/user permissions in the list without inadvertently changing the item permission inside that said list. Here's the code:

```
myList.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);

var roletypes = ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection colRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);
colRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(roletypes);

// if user, add him with read access
if (!item.ContainsKey("group"))
{
     Principal entity = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(item["user"]);
     myList.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(entity).DeleteObject();
     myList.RoleAssignments.Add(entity, colRoleDefinitionBinding);
}
else
{
     Group entity = ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetById(Int32.Parse(item["group"]));
     myList.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(entity).DeleteObject();
     myList.RoleAssignments.Add(entity, colRoleDefinitionBinding);
}

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I'm essentially just removing the user or group and adding them again with their new permissions. When deleting the user/group, if that user or group exist in the item permission then it is also removed. What I dont understand is why the item permission is being tampered when it has unique permissions? Is there another way to change the list permissions without affecting the item permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Just use `ImportRoleDefinitionBindings` to change the permission:

```
Principal entity = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(item["user"]);
roleAssignment = myList.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(entity);
roleAssignment.ImportRoleDefinitionBindings(colRoleDefinitionBinding);
roleAssignment.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```